# Remove indentation from multi-line text in scriban template

Tags: scriban

We use `scriban` templating engine in my team. I am having trouble finding the resource which can help in resolving the following issue:

In this scenario I would like to indent the echo statements(this is simplifying the problem for the sake of this post) for the purpose of improving the readability.

So instead of this:

```
{{ if true -}}
echo "hi"
echo "foo"
echo "bar"
{{ end }}
```

We want this:

```
{{ if true }}
   echo "hi"
   echo "foo"
   echo "bar"
{{ end }}
```

But when we indent the text like above, then it does show up literally like that in generated output. How can I remove the beginning tab or white space from each line of a multi-line text in the generated output?

I tried the `-}}` but this only removes the white space of the beginning line that is the `echo "hi"` line.